# How to check ReportViewer configuration to see which type of MIME types are allowed

Tags: reporting-services, mime-types, reportviewer

I am calling SSRS reports in our application using report viewer. But When i used 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' config setting on the application, all the buttons on the report stopped working.

Because of the MIME type or content type of the JS file from the axd report viewer is blocked.

he resource from “http://localhost/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=9.0.21022.8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.ReportViewer.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

On IIS of the app has the .js MIME type added. But some how it is overwriting content-type to 'text/plain' in the response. Not sure if it is getting changed on reportviewer or somewhere else.

Where can i check the MIME setting for the reportviewer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL rewrite module installed, you can change the Content-Type to the correct value of application/javascript with an outbound rule in web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="ReportViewer js Content-Type" preCondition="Match ReportViewer js file" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Type" pattern="text/plain" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="application/javascript" />
      </rule>
      <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="Match ReportViewer js file">
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Reserved\.ReportViewerWebControl\.axd.*\.js$" />
        </preCondition>
      </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

My application was in a particular folder, so I started the pattern with ^/foldername/Reserved...